# Nested view is coming blank in Ionic

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

Following is my simple routes in **app.js** -

```
  .state('signup', {
    url: '/signup',    
    templateUrl: 'templates/signup.html',
    controller: 'signupCtrl'
  })
  .state('profile', {
    url: '/profile',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/profile.html',
  })  
  .state('profile.init', {
    url: '/profile-init',
    templateUrl: 'templates/profile-init.html'
  })
```

I created a button in `signup` page on click which should take the user to `profile-init` page code - `$state.go('profile.init')`

in **profile.html** I placed -

```
<ion-content style="background: #c3c3c3"></ion-content>
```

in **profile-init.html** page -

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
  <h1 class="title">Profile</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-10"></div>
    <div class="col col-80 padding">
        Thanks for showing your interest
    </div>
    <div class="col col-10">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
<ion-footer-bar class="bar-stable">
  <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="hello()">Forward</button>
</ion-footer-bar>
```

But it is moving to `/#/profile/profile-starter` page but only a background color is coming not text, though I checked the browser console template is loading, let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: the middle content should be wrap inside the `<ion-content>` element.

Comment: @PankajParkar I tried added it my profile-init.html page but still its a blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create ***[ion-nav-view](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/)***

```
<ion-nav-view name="profile"></ion-nav-view>
```

and modify routes in app.js

```
.state('profile.init', {
    url: '/profile-init',
    views: {
        'profile': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/profile-init.html'
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet, and not available to test it but I think you need to use dot ('.') in your file name:

```
templateUrl: 'templates/profile.init.html'
```

And of course change the file name too.